# Multiply matrix by each sublist

Tags: r, list, lapply

I am multplying a matrix `tm` by a vector `tb` to produce a "response" vector. I need to apply this to a list of *n* `tb` vectors, which would produce a list containing *n* response vectors. I am struggling to get this to iterate over the list, for a single case it is this:

```
set.seed(19)
n <- 10
k <- 4
tb <- list(split(rnorm(n*k, 0, 1),seq(1:n)))
tm <- matrix(c(1.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 1.0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 1.0), ncol = k)
tm %*% as.vector(unlist(tb[[1]][1]))
```

Which produces the first response vector when doing this calculation in isolation:

```
> tm %*% as.vector(unlist(tb[[1]][1]))
           [,1]
[1,] -0.4014836
[2,]  0.8348435
[3,]  2.0416294
[4,]  1.9114801
```

However, I've tried to get all 10 response vectors using `lapply`/`sapply` but this gives me an unexpected output:

```
> sapply(tm, function(x) x %*% as.vector(unlist(tb)))
              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]          [,5]
 [1,] -1.189453745 -0.1189453745 -0.2378907491 -0.3568361236 -0.1189453745
 [2,]  0.518629988  0.0518629988  0.1037259975  0.1555889963  0.0518629988
 [3,]  1.423423..   ...               ...           ...
```

Just showing a snippet of the output here, it's 16 columns and 40 rows, in other words - one column per element of the matrix, and *n* x *k* rows. It's seemingly taking the first cell of the matrix, and doing the calculation, then the second cell, and the third cell and so on - as you can see this matches the output from `sapply` when I take a single element of tm:

```
> tm[1] %*% as.vector(unlist(tb[[1]][1]))
          [,1]    [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] -1.189454 0.51863 1.423423 1.504741
```

My question is, **how do I get this multiplication to take the whole matrix when using `lapply`/`sapply` as it does when I do it in isolation?**

Comment: Don't do an `sapply`, do a matrix multiplication: `tm %*% do.call("cbind", tb[[1]])`.

Comment: amazing, thanks - put that as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to remove the `list()` function from your tb definition:

```
set.seed(19)
n <- 10
k <- 4
tb <- split(rnorm(n*k, 0, 1),seq(1:n))
tm <- matrix(c(1.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 1.0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 1.0), ncol = k)
```

you can then produce your first response vector simpler:

```
tm %*% tb[[1]]
[,1]
[1,] -0.4014836
[2,]  0.8348435
[3,]  2.0416294
[4,]  1.9114801
```

and all the response vectors with sapply:

```
sapply(tb, function(x) x %*%tm )

1          2          3           4          5          6          7          8          9         10
[1,] -0.4014836  0.1513720 -0.1113092 -0.28636882  1.1300914 -0.7037464  1.5886556 -0.8908194 -0.6891749 -0.4927336
[2,]  0.8348435  0.6747836  0.6135654 -0.01236765  0.6523212 -0.3599526 -0.2293118  1.5190890  0.1165567 -0.7644372
[3,]  2.0416294 -0.9832891  0.3399474  1.04671293 -0.1986427 -0.4779628  1.3585457  1.0673985 -1.7597788 -0.4059126
[4,]  1.9114801 -0.7064887  0.5356257  0.57154412  0.8048432 -1.6563305  2.9935210 -1.3916476 -1.3746462 -0.9662248
```